# Architecture-Specific Build Settings in Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, x86-64

I'm trying to use architecture-specific build settings in my Xcode Framework so that I can handle the case of the Apple Silicon Mac and the Intel Mac separately. I need to use this build setting as a macro in Metal to check whether the `half` data type is supported on the CPU (it's supported on Apple Silicon but not supported on Intel).

My current implementation uses an xcconfig file with the following line:

`IS_X86_64[arch=x86_64] = 1`

Then, in my build settings I have the following user-defined condition (from the xcconfig):

[image: User-Defined build settings (from the xcconfig)]

I then create the macro `IS_INTEL` so it can be used in Metal:

[image: Creating the IS_INTEL macro for Metal]

## Here's The Problem

In theory I feel like this should work. However, running my Metal app on my Intel mac yields `0` for `IS_X86_64`. The first thing I did was check whether I set up my build setting correctly and replaced

`IS_X86_64[arch=x86_64] = 1`
with
`IS_X86_64[arch=*] = 1`

This worked so I knew that the problem had to be that my current architecture wasn't being represented correctly. Diving further into why this was happening, it turns out that the value for `CURRENT_ARCH` (which should hold the value for the current device architecture that the project is being run on) is `undefined_arch`.

In their [Xcode 10 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/build-system-release-notes-for-xcode-10#:%7E:text=The%20new%20build%20system%20passes,via%20the%20ARCHS%20environment%20variable.), apple mentioned something about `undefined_arch` saying:

> The new build system passes undefined_arch as the value for the ARCH environment variable when running shell script build phases. The value was previously not well defined. Any shell scripts depending on this value must behave correctly for all defined architectures being built, available via the ARCHS environment variable.

However, I'm not building my project on the shell and I don't have any shell scripts.
Does anyone know how I can fix this so that architecture-specific build settings behave as they should?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the architecture via built-in macros. You can see how they are used in `usr/include/TargetConditionals.h`:

```
#if __is_target_arch(x86_64)
    ...
#endif
```

More macros:

```
__is_target_arch(arm64)
__is_target_arch(arm64e)
__is_target_os(ios)
__is_target_environment(macabi)
__is_target_environment(simulator)
```

Comment: The macros in `usr/include/TargetConditionals.h` are different from the ones defined in the `TargetConditionals.h` which can be used in Metal. I tried using `__is_target_arch(x86_64)` but it didn't work :(

Comment: By saying “in Metal” are you talking about the need to check the architecture in a shader?

Comment: Yeah but I need it to be a Macro since I want to use different typedefs for different architectures (using `half` for Arm CPUs and `float` for Intel CPUs)